# importing CSV file into php myadmin gives invalid column count in csv input

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am converting .xlsx file which have hindi mangal font  into csv  and when i am importing it into `phpmyadmin` it gives invalid column count in csv input.

Comment: did you check the columncount in your table v.s the columncount in your csv? maybe give us a line of your csv and your tabledefinition

Comment: Then most probably your column count isn't right on one of the lines of your CSV file. It could be related to a lot of things that we hardly can guess as such. I would suggest splitting the file in 2, testing both to see which one is causing it, and so on until you find the wrong record... if there's only 1...

Comment: I have checked both csv and mytable column are equal

Comment: Column count is one thing to check. Also, make sure each separated string doesn't have commas of it's own. If they do contain commas, then you'll have to wrap the string in quotes as well (Excel is capable of this, but I don't know if it does it by default). Otherwise, the line will be parsed into the incorrect number of columns if there are commas other than the delimiting ones.

Comment: maybe you have a `;` in your data which is interpreted as a delimiter